# how to show hide html table row based on php condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to show/hide table row based on status values of the fetched columns for mysql using php.

**Working Code: This section is working fine**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  
{
$name[] = $row['name'];
$title[] = $row['title'];
$prize[] = $row['prize'];
$status[] = $row['status'];  // this  will save values as enabled or disabled
$points[] = $row['points'];

}


<?php 

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  

{

     echo "<tr> ";
     echo "<td>" .$row[name] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row[points] . "</td>";
        }
     echo "</tr> " ;
?>
```

**Problem: I need solution for this**

I cant display the table as given above due to some more values, that will be taken from other tables, to be shown into the table rows. I am displaying the tables like this.

```
<tr ><td><?php echo "$title[0]";?></td><td>complete <?php echo "$task[0]";?> </td><td></td></tr>
<tr ><td><?php echo "$title[1]";?></td><td>complete <?php echo "$task[1]";?> </td><td></td></tr>
```

**Question:**

> Kindly guide me how I hide or show the rows , as defined in problem
>   section , using the value of
>
> $status[] = $row['status'];

, which will be enabled or disabled

Comment: like that: `if($row['status'] == 1) { display } else { not display }`

Comment: Check your condition in your while (fetch) loop, and if condition matches then display (echo) your stuff. If not, then just skip that part...!

Comment: I know this is easy, Please read problem section , I need to display values in Problem section of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  
{
   if($row['status']=="enabled")
  {
   echo "<tr> ";
   echo "<td>" .$row[name] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" .$row[points] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr> " ;
  }
}
```

For the other lines you can do like this

```
<?php if($status[0] == "enabled") { ?>
    <tr ><td><?php echo "$title[0]";?></td><td>complete <?php echo "$task[0]";?> </td><td></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

**EDIT**

For loop if all your arrays have the same size, you can try something like this

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<sizeof($title);$i++) {
if($status[$i]=="enabled"){
?>
<tr ><td><?php echo $title[$i];?></td><td>complete <?php echo $task[$i];?> </td><td></td></tr>
<?php  }
} ?>
```

Comment: If you are displaying each row one by one, yes. If you find a solution for display them with a boucle it would be easier.

Comment: This is what I am looking for ,, simple one condition on the top to all rows, and it should do the trickj, can you suggest something using  ( $[status[i] == "enabled" ) , something like using for loop, so that I need to put this condition only once and it should work ... I will accept current solution, as it will solve the problem partially.

Comment: I will test it now, Can you please explain this ,,($i=0;$i<sizeof($title);$i++) .. How will it work. with ($title)

Comment: If all your arrays have the same size then you can take the size of one and loop one by one. it works with all other arrays, we just need a referal size.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you, it just an example, i think you need to use `<table>` also.

```
<?php 
echo "<table border='1'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  
{
  if($row['status'] == 1){
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" .$row['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" .$row['points'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }  
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

**Side Note:**

Stop using `mysql_*` extension its deprecated and close in PHP 7, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)): ?>
    <?php if($row['status'] == 'enabled'):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['points']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php continue; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        if($row['status'] == 'enabled'){
            echo '<tr><td>' . $row[name] . '</td><td>' . $row[points] . '</td></tr>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I need to add some more values taken from other tables, That Why i am using it like this. else it would have been a straight forward .

Comment: So ur asking for a sql query containing a inner join between more tables to return all the needed values? If that's the case then we would need your DB structure as tables and rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  
{
    if($row['status']=='enabled') {
        echo "<tr> ";
        echo "<td>" .$row[name] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row[points] . "</td>";    
        echo "</tr> " ;
    }
}
?>
```

If `$row['status']=='enabled'` is false, it will just go to the next loop.

Comment: Please see the edit
edit: Seems I'm still missing something in your question. Care to clarify what it is?

Comment: This is easy , Please see the Problem section, I need to add some more vallues ,

Comment: Three of us answered almost the same answers, so I guess it is safe to assume that the problem is in your question. Please consider updating your question, you might get what you're looking for the first time.

Comment: I have edited the question , I guess at first I did not clarify the question well.