# Hide specific row of a table based on the value of a Variable

Tags: php

I am working with an Invoice in php. I want to show the DUE part only if there is any due in the invoice otherwise it should remain hide. In my printOrder.php the codes are given below:

Here is the total code of printOrder.php file:

```
    <?php   

require_once 'core.php';

$orderId = $_POST['orderId'];

$sql = "SELECT order_date, client_name, client_address, client_contact, sub_total, vat, total_amount, discount, grand_total, paid, due, invoice_no FROM orders WHERE order_id = $orderId";

$orderResult = $connect->query($sql);
$orderData = $orderResult->fetch_array();

$orderDate = $orderData[0];
$clientName = $orderData[1];
$clientAddress = $orderData[2];
$clientContact = $orderData[3];
$subTotal = $orderData[4];
$vat = $orderData[5];
$totalAmount = $orderData[6]; 
$discount = $orderData[7];
$grandTotal = $orderData[8];
$paid = $orderData[9];
$due = $orderData[10];
$invoiceNo = $orderData[11];


$orderItemSql = "SELECT order_item.product_id, order_item.rate, order_item.quantity, order_item.total,
product.product_name, order_item.categories_name, order_item.subcategory_name, order_item.brand_name FROM order_item
    INNER JOIN product ON order_item.product_id = product.product_id 
 WHERE order_item.order_id = $orderId";
$orderItemResult = $connect->query($orderItemSql);



$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);

?>

<table border="0" cellpadding="5" style="width:100%;font-size:10px;border:0px solid black;text-align:center;margin-bottom:15px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <img style="float:left" src="assests/images/logo.jpg" width="80"/>
            </th>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan="5">
                <div>
                    <div style="font-size:14px; text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Sylhet Gym Supplements & Online Store</div>
                    <div style="font-size:8px; text-align:right; font-weight:normal; line-height:10px; padding:4px 0 4px 30px">One of the best UK and USA suppliers in Gym Food Supplements to support A healthy lifestyle. We supply To retailer Bodybuilding.com supplement Online Market, Sylhet, Bangladesh</div>
                    <div style="font-size:9px; text-align:right; font-weight:normal">R.B Complex (Level-4), East Zindabazar, Sylhet</div>
                    <div style="font-size:9px; text-align:right; font-weight:normal; line-height:18px">Cell: 01725-275252</div>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="8" style="text-align:left;margin-left:0;padding-left:0"><span style="font-size:10px;background-color:#000;color:#fff;padding:2px 15px 4px">Invoice Details</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="padding:5px 15px; text-align:left"><b>Mr. <?php echo $clientName; ?><b><br><p style="font-weight:normal;line-height:14px;"><?php echo $clientAddress; ?><br><?php echo $clientContact; ?></p></th>
            <th colspan="4" bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="line-height:14px;padding:5px 15px; font-weight:normal;text-align:right">Invoice No :&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><?php echo $invoiceNo; ?></b><br>Invoice Date :&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><?php echo $orderDate; ?></b><br><br>Paid Amount :&nbsp;&nbsp;Tk <span style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold"><?php echo $paid; ?></span> Only</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="8"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#f4f4f4">Sl.</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f4f4f4" colspan="4" style="text-align:center">Product Description</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="width:80px">Rate</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="width:80px">Qty</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="text-align:right;width:80px">Total</th>
        </tr>

        <?php

        $x = 1;
        while($row = $orderItemResult->fetch_array()) {         

        ?>
            <tr>
                <th style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal;"><?php echo $x; ?></th>
                <th colspan="2" style="font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:left"><?php echo $row[4]; ?></th>
                <th colspan="2" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; text-align:left">A Product of <b><?php echo $row[7]; ?></b><br>It\'s Flavor is <b><?php echo $row[5]; ?></b>&nbsp;(<?php echo $row[6]; ?>)</th>
                <th style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal;"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></th>
                <th style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal;"><?php echo $row[2]; ?></th>
                <th style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal;text-align:right"><?php echo $row[3]; ?></th>
            </tr>

        <?php 

        $x++;
        } // /while

        ?>

        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="8" style="border-top:1px solid #eee"></th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan="3" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:bold; line-height:8px; text-align:right">Total Amount</th>
            <th style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; line-height:8px; text-align:right"><?php echo $totalAmount; ?></th>
        </tr>   

        <tr>


            <?php

            if ($due > 0) {
                echo '<th colspan="3" style="border:1px solid #ccc">Condition : &nbsp;&nbsp;'.$due.' Tk will be T.T</th>';
            } else {
                echo '<th colspan="3"></th>';
            }

            ?>

            <th></th>
            <th colspan="3" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:bold; line-height:8px; text-align:right">Discount</th>
            <th style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; line-height:8px; text-align:right"><?php echo $discount; ?></th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan="3" style="font-size:9px; font-weight:bold; line-height:8px; text-align:right">Grand Total</th>
            <th style="font-size:9px; font-weight:normal; line-height:8px; text-align:right"><?php echo $grandTotal; ?></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="8" bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="text-align:right;text-transform:capitalize">Amount (In Words) : <?php echo $f->format($grandTotal); ?> Taka Only.</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="8" style="position:absolute; width:100%; bottom:50px;"><span style="float:left;border-top:1px solid #ccc">&nbsp;&nbsp;Customer Signature&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="float:right;border-top:1px solid #ccc;margin-right:20px">&nbsp;&nbsp;For Sylhet Gym Supplements&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="8" style="background-color: #eee; color: #555; position:absolute; width:100%; height:9px; line-height:9px; bottom:0; font-size: 7px">Powered By 7CoderIT. For assistance call on 01744-123456</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<?php

$connect->close();

?>
```

I have changed few things to accomplish my want. After that the code looks like above.

Comment: What is `paid`? Maybe use `CASE` or `coalesce` depending on the definition.

Comment: @JahangirHossain I cannot post a new answer because you haven't provided the details that I have requested above.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice ur comments. I m uploading the code.

Comment: That's a big batch of code for me to look over.  Now, what isn't working as desired?  What is `$due`? Is it a `0` or a `null` value?  It looks like your colspan declarations are "better" in your actual project (`<tbody>` rows still need to be corrected).

Comment: The problem was in due value. I couldn't hide the row of due value if the amount is zero. Actually I was messing html with php. But then separated the tags of php and html's. This is the final approach:

 <?php

            if ($due > 0) {
                echo '<th colspan="3" style="border:1px solid #ccc">Condition : &nbsp;&nbsp;'.$due.' Tk will be T.T</th>';
            } else {
                echo '<th colspan="3"></th>';
            }

            ?>
Now it's working fine.

Comment: So now, your question (as it is posted) doesn't have a problem anymore?  Then this page will be mostly confusing for future researchers.  Just be sure to cast your `$_POST` value as `int` before using in your queries.  `$orderId = (int)$_POST['orderId'];`

Comment: The script is for product selling invoice. If the amount is fully paid then the value of $due is stored as zero in db. If the amount isn't fully paid then the rest from total amount will be shown as due value or more precisely the value of $due. My asking was how can I hide if $due = 0; that's it.

Comment: Yes, @webDev , please cut out all of the other snippets in your answer and only provide guidance for the conditional.  Then you won't be giving any misleading information about the rest of the broken table structure.

Comment: Yape as u told. My problem is solved. Now anything can happen for this post. Sorry again for messing things here.

Comment: Sure @mickmackusa, thanks for your guidance and suggestions. Thanks a lot

Comment: When I first came to StackOverflow, my first posts were definitely not "award-winning".  There is a learning curve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show hide html table row based on php condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766512/how-to-show-hide-html-table-row-based-on-php-condition)

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the due value right, I assume you get due amount 0 or null or some value

```
<?php 
    if($due>0&&$due!=""){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"><?php echo $due; ?></th>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

If your $due variable does not help you to decide, then check the variable which decides that due part, include the due part inside an if condition, something like following (General PHP)

```
if(condition){ //this tr will be printed only if your condition will be true.
   echo '<tr>.....</tr>';
}
```

**UPDATE: Example displaying conditional row in a table** 
Single PHP File

```
<?php 
    $total_amount = 100;
    $due = 20;
    $data = array();
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        foreach($data as $d){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>

        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"><?php echo $total_amount ?></th>
        </tr>

        <?php 
        if($due>0&&$due!=""){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"><?php echo $due; ?></th>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Use colspan property of the td and th to match with the number of columns in a table.

Comment: I couldn't run the condition inside html. It shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\printOrder.php
on line 105

Comment: include all your PHP code inside <?php ?> tag. If you are printing the table using php string then break the string and then use the condition. that error is simply you have messed up with html and php code. Please look at how to include html code inside php and how to include php code inside html both ways. I have just posted idea how to do that, or post your full code how you are writing your php code

Comment: yes as a php string.

$table = ' <table>.....</table>';
echo $table;

I m newbie in php. Its my bad I can't get it.

Comment: just break that down, code the php tag and write html table. Its bad practice to use all the html code inside php string. Hard to debug and irritating. See my update and create one page based on that structure, see carfully where i have opened the php tag and where i have closed the php tag.

Comment: I m really really grateful to you webDev bro. I did it. The condition is working fine and I m really very happy.

Comment: @mickmackusa yeah you are right but the user is very beginner and he needs to understand how things works on php and html first. and then he can later build the markup based on his project and maintain consistency, Based on your comment I would suggest user to look at the prepared statements for query and handling views/ui on PHP in modern ways (google).

Comment: I accept that, please edit the post and if needed mark as delete. Please edit the post so that the user can understand how to use the conditions. Also please include what you suggest to the user please sir

Comment: yape sure..I will. I have many things to learn. Thanks for the guideline webDev and mickmackusa.

Comment: It's my bad I couldn't make an obvious question. I m sorry for that. I m eagerly waiting for the post. Can't wait to learn new ways. TIA